# How to pass values from layout inflater in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am using layout inflater to get value for amount and vat using edit text in layout inflater.When the user press the save button it stores the value in text view.
I want the values stored in text view layout inflater to Main Activity.I have tried declaring the values globally but it is not working.

```
LayoutInflater repcard=LayoutInflater.from(Cam.this);
    View promptView=repcard.inflate(R.layout.moneyreceipt,null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Cam.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
   final EditText amt=(EditText)promptView.findViewById(R.id.edamt);
   final EditText vta=(EditText)promptView.findViewById(R.id.edvat);
   final TextView  tvs=(TextView)promptView.findViewById(R.id.tvamount);
   final TextView tvat=(TextView)promptView.findViewById(R.id.tvvat);

    final Button save=(Button)promptView.findViewById(R.id.btnmoneysave);
    tvs.setText(amt.getText().toString());
    tvat.setText(vta.getText().toString());
    amount=tvs.getText().toString();
    vat=tvat.getText().toString();
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(Cam.this, amount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(Cam.this, vat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            detailsreceiptupload();

        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
```

In this the variables amount and vat are declared globally.

Comment: And what you want exactly? when press save button values from vat and amount  to be send to another activity or what? Sorry for this but i dont understand clearly your question.

Comment: I want the values stored in the text view to be passed to the amount and vat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think event getText and setText outside the onClickListener. It didn't display any values when you click button save. You can try:

```
LayoutInflater repcard=LayoutInflater.from(Cam.this);
View promptView=repcard.inflate(R.layout.moneyreceipt,null);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Cam.this);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);


   final EditText amt=(EditText)promptView.findViewById(R.id.edamt);
   final EditText vta=(EditText)promptView.findViewById(R.id.edvat);
   final TextView  tvs=(TextView)promptView.findViewById(R.id.tvamount);
   final TextView tvat=(TextView)promptView.findViewById(R.id.tvvat);

   final Button save=(Button)promptView.findViewById(R.id.btnmoneysave);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        tvs.setText(amt.getText().toString());
        tvat.setText(vta.getText().toString());
        amount=tvs.getText().toString();
        vat=tvat.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(Cam.this, amount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(Cam.this, vat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        detailsreceiptupload();

    }
});
AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You assigned the vat and amount values from the EditTexts outside the onClickListener. How exactly do you expect those values to change? Put inside the onClickListener all the things that you want to happen when the button is clicked !

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        vat=tvat.getText().toString();
        amount=tvs.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(Cam.this, amount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(Cam.this, vat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        detailsreceiptupload();

    }
});
```

Comment: It didn't display any values in toast

Comment: No i didn't used numeric variables i have passed the values from edit text to text view inside the layout inflater.And i want to pass the values in text view to a string which is declared globally.

Comment: Does the toast message pop up and it's empty? Or it doesn't show up at all?

Comment: The amount and vat has been decalred as string then why we have to use the Integer.toString

Comment: that was my bad...I didn't notice that your values were String allready. I edited my answer and deleted that comment